# Can I publish a downlading app on play console?

Tags: android, publish, google-play-console, playback

sorry for my stupid question but I want to know if I can upload an app to play console where users can download files such as zip, apk, txt etc.

Please let me know if it is allowed to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, for example you can upload a internet browser, with a internet browser you can search in the internet and dowload anything without problem

Comment: I actually want to make an app where user will click the desired file and he will be redirected to mediafire to download the file. Is it allowed on play console?